# How to create custom UICollectionViewCell using Storyboard in iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I have a `UIViewController` in which I have a `UICollectionView`.The cells of the `UICollectionView` need to be images so I understand that I need to subclass the `UICollectionViewCell` class. So basically, I need a UIViewController which has a UICollectionView that has a custom UICollectionViewCell. I am using a storyboard and when I need to create a custom `UITableVieCell`, I do the following:

- Create a subclass of `UITableViewCell`
- Set this subclass as the class for the `UITableViewCell` in the storyboard
- Set a reuse identifier.
- Import this class in my view controller implementation, declare a cell of this subclass and proceed.

But when I follow the same for a `UICollectionViewCell`, **for eg.** I create a subclass called `CustomCollectionViewCell`, and declare it in the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` like

```
CustomCollectionViewCell *cell = (CustomCollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSLog(@"%@",cell);
```

This logs `<UICollectionViewCell: 0x137529010; frame = (10 10; 300 164); layer = <CALayer: 0x170220880>>` no matter what I do. I can just not initialize my custom `UICollectionViewCell` class and hence cannot add the images.

I looked at other StackOverflow answers and read answers saying not to do this:

```
[self.collectionView registerClass:[CustomCollectionViewCell class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

if I'm using storyboard, so I commented it out.

All the reuse identifiers, outlets etc have been set. I can't seem to find where the error is.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you set `CustomCollectionViewCell` as the class for `CollectionView` in storyboard?

Comment: I did. After some further testing, I realised this.
When I do, 
`CustomCell *cell = [[CustomCell alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@",[cell class])`, it returns `CustomCell`. But when I do, `cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];`, it returns `UICollectionViewCell`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

set your custom collectionview cell class in `Identity Inspector` like

[image]

and in `cellForItemAtIndexPath`

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    CollectionViewCell *cell = (CollectionViewCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"%@", cell);
    return cell;
}
```

and got log as

```
<CollectionViewCell: 0x7af70000; baseClass = UICollectionViewCell; frame = (0 0; 70 69); clipsToBounds = YES; opaque = NO; layer = <CALayer: 0x7af70210>>
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

It was a stupid mistake. The reuse identifier that I was using was already being used by a different cell someplace else. Changed it and it works perfectly now.